# Need to prevent access to a certain feature while an upgrade is being installed

Tags: c#, sql-server, registry, windows-installer

Our product allows updates to be installed via an MSI installer.  An update consists of several files which need to be copied to disk, and the addition of database entries which the installer adds by running several SQL scripts.

Updates can be (and commonly are) installed while the main executable is open.  Because of this, I need a way of preventing access to a certain database-intensive feature while the upgrade is in progress.

My current thoughts:

1. Installer adds a registry key when it starts up.
2. Update is installed.
3. On success or failure, the registry key is deleted.

Meanwhile, the application (written in C#) queries for the presence of the registry key, displaying an error dialog if it is set.

Is this reliable?  I'm concerned about what happens if the user kills the installer via task manager, then the registry key will never be deleted and the user will be permanently locked out of the feature.  Also not sure about any race conditions that the above solution could lead to.

Any suggestions about whether this approach is feasible, or a better approach?

Comment: Does the application use an account in SQL Server that you could disable for the duration of the update?

Comment: @user92546 - Yes, this is possible.  But then within my application I won't necessarily know that the DB connection fails because a) an installer is running or b) there is a more serious SQL Server connection issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer already implements a Mutex to indicate that an installation is in progress.  Just code your database intensive code to check for that mutex and no-op while it's present.  Nothing additional needs to be done.

(Note: using this will stop your processing any time MSI is installing a product which is probably not a bad idea anyways.  If you want a unique mutex, it's trivial to write a custom action. )

[_MSIExecute Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Update by @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat

The above answer did what I needed.  This is the code I ended up using:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(@"Global\_MSIExecute");
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Installation in progress!");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mutex was abandoned");
        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MSI installer not running");
        }

        // Perform operation here
    }
```

Comment: Please see my related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091216/abandonedmutexexception-for-system-mutex-not-caught-on-2nd-run-when-1st-run-kill . Are you suggesting that if I replace `foobar` in that code with `_MSIExecute`, it should do what I want?  I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to say Global\\_MSIExecute.  Also, the _MSIExecute mutex is only present when the installer is past the InstallUISequence and actually in the InstallExecuteSequence performing installation activities.  If you just have the installer up at the Welcome screen it won't be there.  Both of these statements are on the web page I linked to.

Comment: Also you should be calling OpenExistingMutex to see if the MSI mutex exists. It's not yours to create and own.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - this worked.  I added the code that I used to your answer (hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 2):

Would using a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01985e8f.aspx) be reasonable here?  Require that the intensive tasks and the updater first acquire the mutex before executing.

**EDIT:** I lied about wrapping the mutex in a `using` will protect you from task manager shutdowns.  Makes sense, you wouldn't expect `finally` blocks to execute either.  What you'll end up with is an AbandonedMutex, which is discussed in the msdn article I linked.

Also saw recently a useful little [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/the-misunderstood-mutex.aspx) about using a Mutex to prevent multiple instances of the same program from executing.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.  From the installer, I'm assuming it would need to launch a standalone executable which acquires the mutex, which then terminates after the installation is complete.  Unless there's a way to access the samed name mutex directly from MSI - do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I think there shouldn't be anything stopping you from acquiring the Mutex as part of the MSI installation code, though I've never tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER DATABASE <name> SINGLE_USER
```

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) will break all other connections and allow you to proceed with the update.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I want to be able to print a meaningful message from within my application - something like "The installer is currently running".  I won't know that the installer is definitely running in this case; there may be a database connection problem instead.